# GIMP: Change image color with different shades

Tags: gimp

How I can change the colour shaded here to green, dark green, and light green in Gimp?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a GIMP expert here but you can probably achieve what you are looking for by changing the settings from **Colors** -> **Hue / Saturation** -> **Select "Master"** -> change the values according to your needs.
The folowing screenshot should give you an idea:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it with GIMP to get dark green, green and light green instead of an undifferentiated green pattern like this.

[image]

Here are the settings I used to get an interesting effect with a variety of different shades of green.

*Filters* -> *G'MIC* -> *Colors* -> *Channel processing*
This exaggerates the contrast between the different shades of turquoise in the original picture.

The G'MIC GIMP Plugin does not come with the standard GIMP package, but it can be easily installed in Ubuntu from the Ubuntu Software Center where GMIC's package name is *gimp-gmic*. For other platforms G'MIC can be downloaded from the [G'MIC website](https://gmic.eu/gimp.shtml).

[image]

*Colors* -> *Colorize*
This changes the dominant color from turquoise to green.

[image]